# How to Get Spring Boot Application Root Path?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring **Boot** Applications Use **Embedded Tomcat/Jetty** **So** How to Get Spring Boot Application Root Path?

Comment: What do you mean? Also are you using Maven, Gradle, or something else?

Comment: I am using maven. in spring mvc we deploy our app in containers like external tomcat/jetty but in spring boot, tomcat is embedded and it's just simple java application with main method. how to get application root path.

Comment: I mean relative/physical path.

Comment: Why do you need this? generally this is because you are trying to do something that isn't going to work in this scenario anyway (nor should you generally do things like that anyway imho).

Comment: I am trying to create a folder in my application and save uploaded files in that so i need my application root folder relative path.

Answer (score 1):

In **Spring MVC** applications we deploy our application to external tomcat contianer so we can use **HttpServletRequest** class to find root folder path.

But in **Spring Boot** application using with **HttpServletRequest** does not return application root folder path. **Spring Boot** application is java application with **main** method.

So I use this **Workaround**. **If you find any better way, share with me. thanks.**

```
YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

[CodeSource.getLocation()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html) Returns the **URL** location associated with code source.

[URL.getPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath()) Gets the **path** part of **URL**.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.