# Application Root Path of Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, spring-boot

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074038/how-to-get-spring-boot-application-root-path) is not a standard way to get application root path (file system path). I need to upload a file to a directory e.g. uploads created in application main directory. How can I get the application root path in my Java Class. I am developing Rest API. Please help in this regard.

Comment: The files I want to upload can be read and write e.g. text files. Thats why choosing **Resource** directory is not a standard way to upload such files.

Comment: I tested  `@Autowired
ServletContext context; context.getRealPath("uploads");`  this solution in a Spring Boot Standalone application. But it gives the path `/tmp/tomcat-docbase.841921421577111254.8080/resources/upload‌​‌​s which is not the real path I want. Actually I want the path like /home/bahadar/workspace/project/uploads/

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/get-current-web-application

Comment: @AliSohrabi Followed above link but it is giving me this path: /C:/Users/150314/Avneet/workspace/hrbca2023/hrbweb/build/classes/java/main/
I dont think this is the right root path.

Answer (score 17):

If I understand right, you want to develop a REST API which aims to upload a file to directory that located in your application directory. It's recommended to create file,images,.. in resources directory. And basically you should be using servlet context to get the absolute path of this directory. First you need servletContext

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;
```

Then you can get absolute and **relative directory("resources/uploads")**:

```
String absolutePath = context.getRealPath("resources/uploads");
File uploadedFile = new File(absolutePath, "your_file_name");
```

EDITED:

You would like to develop rest api. So you can create a controller class first

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FileController {

@Autowired
ServletContext context;

@PostMapping("/upload") 
public String fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (file.isEmpty()) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Please load a file");
    }

    try {

        // Get the file and save it uploads dir
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(context.getRealPath("uploads") + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "success";
}

}
```

There is another way to manage file operations and Spring Boot documentation explained very well: [Uploading Files Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

Comment: Usually, **Resource** directory is used for static/read-only resources. I want to put files out of resource directory and these files can be read and write. E.g text files etc.

Comment: @BahadarAli You can still create a directory is located under the project dir. And upload files here

Comment: As a spring boot application is a standalone, therefore the absolutePath in your case is `/tmp/tomcat-docbase.841921421577111254.8080/resources/uploads`

Comment: Yes I can create a directory in project dir (application main directory). But my question is that how can i access the relative or absolute path of that directory in a JAVA class of spring boot application.

Comment: @BahadarAli I edited code with rest api part. You can achieve your problem to use `ServletContext` or you should look at  `StorageService` in Spring Boot doc. If someone knows another ways, it would be grateful to share

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But If you test this code in a Spring Boot application. The `context.getRealPath("uploads")` will give `/tmp/tomcat-docbase.841921421577111254.8080/resources/upload‌​s` which is not the real path I want. Actually I want the path like `/home/bahadar/workspace/project/uploads/`.

Comment: ok so you don't need to get `ServletContext` just do it like this : 
`Path path = Paths.get("/home/bahadar/workspace/project/uploads/" + file.getOriginalFilename());`

Comment: ServletContext doesn't seem to be a spring annotation

Comment: @obesechicken13 you should google it. And don't forget to search by the spring version you use

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use [FileSystemResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html) to get the root directory:

```
new FileSystemResource("").getFile().getAbsolutePath()
```

---

**Non spring way:**

Alternatively, you can also get it using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. This works with `properties`, `yml` or `pom.xml` files as well.

```
# properties file
info.root-dir=${user.dir}
```

---

```
<!-- pom.xml -->
<properties> <!-- not really sure if anyone would ever do it -->
    <another.project.dir>${user.dir}/../someproject</another.project.dir>
</properties>
```

Comment: Have been searching for correct variable name for long time. Found `user.dir` from your answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: @anubhava I am glad my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

**You may user bellow like which is working for me**

1. Here is my image directory in spring boot

[image]

2. In my controller you can use bellow code for load file

   ```
   @Autowired
   ServletContext context;    

       @GetMapping(value = "/loadfile/{filename}")
       @ResponseBody
       public ResponseEntity<Resource> loadResourcefile(@PathVariable(required = false) String filename) {
         //get file path
         String absolutePath = context.getRealPath("resources/file-repository");
         Resource file = loadFileResource(filename,absolutePath);
         return ResponseEntity.ok()
           .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
           .body(file);
      }


    public Resource loadFileResource(String filename, String filePath) {
        try {        
           filePath = filePath + filename;
           File file = new File(filePath);
           if (file.exists()) {
             InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);           
              return new InputStreamResource(in);
         }

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {             
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
     return null;
    }
   ```